# Unable to login to my old local User/Profile

Tags: windows-7, networking, windows-server-2012, user-profiles

I am running a Windows 7 on my Laptop. Quite recently our office got a Windows Server 2012. Now the IT guy created a Domain User on my laptop to connect to the server.

Afterwords when I tried to login to my old local user the widows created a new profile folder, in my old profile there are all the setting for firewalls, Mozilla Profile (Bookmarks, Password), Outlook Mails, Chrome and so much more.

Now when I went to the user folder the folder for old profile is still there (thanks to God) but I cannot login to it. The folders are as follows,

`Andeel` (Old local User)

`Andeel.Andeel-PC` (New local User)

`Andeel.Dumont` (Domain User)

Kindly help me reconnect to my old profile. Thank you in advance for you assistance.

Regards

Comment: Its entirely possible your IT department disable the account, to prevent you from accessing it, since they want you to use the domain account now.  If your domain user has local Administrator permissions you can take ownership of the old user profile folder and simply access the folder.  Doing so will break the user profile which owns the folder.

Answer (score 0):

The way to login to a local profile on a domain joined PC is to type this on the login screen:

`.\LOCAL-USERNAME`

Remember to replace `LOCAL-USERNAME` with your username. This works because `.\` is the same as specifying the local PC name, which in turn tells Windows to use that login server (be it local or remote) to login

Comment: Tried but it didn't work. The windows still logged in to the new local user it created Andeel.Andeel-PC

Comment: @AndeelUsman it should work, that's how you access a local account from a PC joined to a domain...